# Embaralhar cartas de baralho

Tags: c#

Preciso fazer uma espécie de "Mini-Pife", porém não estou conseguindo criar o método para embaralhar as cartas, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
public class Baralho
{
    public Carta[] Cartas { get; private set; }

    public Baralho()
    {
        this.Cartas = new Carta[52];

        int c = 0;

        for (int nIdx = 0; nIdx < 4; ++nIdx)
        {
            Naipe naipe = (Naipe)(nIdx + 1);

            for (int vIdx = 0; vIdx < 13; ++vIdx)
            {
                Valor valor = (Valor)(vIdx + 1);

                this.Cartas[c++] = new Carta()
                {
                    Naipe = naipe,
                    Valor = valor
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public class Baralho
{
    public Carta[] Cartas { get; private set; }

    public Baralho()
    {
        this.Cartas = new Carta[52];

        int c = 0;

        for (int nIdx = 0; nIdx < 4; ++nIdx)
        {
            Naipe naipe = (Naipe)(nIdx + 1);

            for (int vIdx = 0; vIdx < 13; ++vIdx)
            {
                Valor valor = (Valor)(vIdx + 1);

                this.Cartas[c++] = new Carta()
                {
                    Naipe = naipe,
                    Valor = valor
                };
            }
        }
        this.Cartas = Embaralha(this.Cartas);
    }

    public Carta[] Embaralha(Carta[] baralho){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return MyArray.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();  
    }

}
```

Retirado daqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net

Dica: Queria dar uma dica que vai ajudar a agilizar os seus estudos/trabalho com programação. Sua situação é: você tem um `Array` de `Cartas` e você precisa embaralhar essas `Cartas`... Você não precisa se prender nas `Cartas` e sim nos recursos que você está usando(`Array`).

Se cada `Carta` está dentro de um `Array`, então você precisa randomizar um `Array` o que tem dentro do `Array` não importa(no seu caso são `Cartas`) ou seja você teria ganho muito mais tempo se tivesse procurado "Como randomizar um `Array`" e já teria encontrado a solução,não precisaria esperar uma resposta aqui. Bom, não é uma crítica negativa e sim construtiva espero que lhe ajude.